# How can I create a plot that defines a sequence of actions?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, sequence, rscript

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame( frame = 1:25,
              value = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A","A","C","C","C","B","B","A",
                   "A","C","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D","C","A","A"))
```

I would like to be able to generate a plot showing the sequence and weight as shown in the figure

[image: example]

Comment: Where is `weight` defined? The image shows a sequence of 5, which works well but if you were to try to include all activities that might cause significant crowding.

Comment: It could be fine even without the definition of a weight, so just the sequence.

Comment: What is the rule for managing consecutive values? do you expect the first four values to be `A->A->A->B->`?

Comment: I would like to achieve this A->B ->A->C-> B,  so deleting the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach using `ggplot`

It's built up with a helper data frame based on run length encoding for the values. You may find you have to fiddle with positioning the arrow head by editing the `arr_end` variable. I've ignored the start of the arrow as this is covered by the point.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame( frame = 1:25,
                  value = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A","A","C","C","C","B","B","A",
                            "A","C","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D","C","A","A"))

df_rle <- data.frame(len = rle(df$value)[[1]],
                     val = rle(df$value)[[2]],
                     group = 1) |> 
  mutate(cum = cumsum(len),
         arr_end = lead(cum - 0.5 * len) - 0.7)



ggplot(df_rle)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = cum - len,  xmax = cum, ymin = 0, ymax = 0.05,
                fill = val))+
  geom_text(aes(label = val, x = cum - 0.5*len, y = -0.03))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = cum - 0.5*len, xend = arr_end, y = -0.02, yend = -0.02),
               arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.25,"cm"), ends="last", type = "closed") )+
  geom_point(aes(x = cum - 0.5*len, y = -0.02, fill = val, colour = val), shape = 21, size = 10, show.legend = FALSE)+
  theme_void()
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>